# Where is this gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

I have a system where I use the gem [`sinatra-activerecord`](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord) (required by `sinatra/activerecord` in my Rakefile by requiring `sinatra/activerecord/rake`. I've looked in rubygems and there is no gem called `sinatra-activrecord-rake`, so what part of `sinatra-activerecord` is it? Also, how could I make part of my gem require-able this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you require `sinatra/activerecord/rake`, you are actually requiring the `rake` file within the gem.

Specifically, [this is the file](https://github.com/janko-m/sinatra-activerecord/blob/master/lib/sinatra/activerecord/rake.rb) that the library is requiring. It's not from any `sinatra-activerecord-rake` gem.